# Brother laser printers no longer detected on USB

Tags: usb, brother-printer, all-in-one

I have two all-in-one laser printers from Brother, which — within a few weeks of each other — have become **no longer detected on USB**.

Symptoms:

- I cannot hear any sound when connecting the USB cable from the printer to a computer
- From the computer it is no longer possible to print nor to scan.

The first printer is a MFC-9460CDN and the second one a DCP-9020CDW.

I tried with different USB cables and different computers, running different OS (Windows 7, Windows 10, Linux Ubuntu).

As the contact at the printer USB socket appeared to me a bit loose, I suspected that the problem could come from there.

On the DCP-9020CDW printer, I checked and optimized the contact at the USB socket:

1. removed plasturgy, motherboard cache, and cables,
2. removed the motherboard,
3. checked that the female connector on the motherboard was firmly soldered.
4. melted the solder surrounding the four electric pins of the USB connector, adding some tin, to make sure that there is no bad contact there,
5. using tweezers, slightly pulled out the small golden springs of the USB connector, in order to ensure a better contact with the cable,
6. put the motherboard back in place and reconnected the cables.

Thanks to point 5, the USB connection is no longer loose, but **the problem persists**.

I also tried resetting the computer to factory settings without more success.

Apart from the connection, the all-in-one is perfectly working.
For example, I can copy documents.

In the printer settings are options for the Network. I assume the printer possibly switched to Network mode but cannot find a way to tell him using USB, altough it was configured to use USB and not the Network.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem and how did you solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to try these printers on a different computer?  Re-soldering the USB connection and trying to make the pins better may not have worked as well as hoped for.

Comment: @John: Quite possibly you're right, but the unexplained part is why one printer kept on working several weeks after the other. I wonder if the power at the poster's home is safe.

Comment: Use ubuntu - easiest methods of USB checking. Plugin to ubuntu, open terminal and type lsusb - put the list here

Comment: Not sure if Brother has implemented this, but HP *kills* printers with the wrong ink, or that have run out of ink -- not only for printing, but for other uses, too, including copying and scanning. https://www.howtogeek.com/403346/hps-ink-subscription-has-drm-that-disables-your-printer-cartridges/ . That said, have you experienced any *power surges*, or a disconnected neutral wire (which causes huge voltage imbalance)?

Comment: @John: As mentioned in my post, the printers were tested with different computers ; I meant several ones, from different models. The existing solder appeared to me in good condition. I heated it with heat gun, likely around 300°C (because of the large heat sink) to possibly fill invisible micro-cracks, and added some tin on the back of solder points. However, I don't think the problem coming from here, unless possibly the USB socket itself, which I should possibly replace.

Comment: @harrymc: The power at my office is safe. I tested that the DCP-9020CDW printer is detected if wired through the RJ45 network socket, but not in USB. I have used both printers on a computer where the USB socket was a bit loose but still working. The printers are not detected on other computers with USB socket in good condition.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas: Good suggestion. I already had tested with Ubuntu and tested again. The lsusb command doesn't list any additional controler when any of the printers is connected. Windows device manager also doesn't list anything more when one of the printers is connected. So, there is simply no communication with the USB port.

Comment: Seems like USB is just dead for these printers.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik: Thanks for your comment. The printers recently had empty toners. On the DCP-9020CDW, it was initially replaced by original used low toner (and toner level reset done) and then by an original new toner. On the MFC-9460CDN has low yellow toner. Even with low toner, it was possible to scan documents, but now the all-in-one printers are even not listed in the TWAIN sources when one wasnts to scan.